# How do I display, change and save values through a website on a local server?

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I'm the hostess of a pen&paper game and I wanted to provide my group with a little local web application to use as character sheets.

I'm totally new to everything including a server, html and javascript. I managed to set up my local apache server, was able to access the correct index.html and customize it. So far I'm very proud :)

Now I want to be able to put in my stats and talents on the website, which then should be saved somehow. Those integers and strings should also be loaded, if the website is accessed another time or reloaded. Those values should survive a reboot.

I thought of one text file per player just like a save game, but I have absolutly no idea how i could access those values with html, javascript or even a c programm.

I researched all day and couldn't come up with anything usefull. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: You will need a database, and some knowledge of a server-side programming language. Perhaps some tutorials would better help you, because this takes a lot of experience to set up.

Comment: Thanks, I looked into PHP and MySQL and now I'm getting somewhere :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want just a simple database so that your page can load some data, you can use JSON files served locally and load them with javascript, something like this:

JSON File(player1.json):

```
{ "name": "John", "age": 30 }
```

JS

```
function getPlayer(playerName) {
  var url = window.location.origin + '/' + playerName + '.json'; // www.site.com/playerName.json
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open(window.location.origin, theUrl, false ); // false for synchronous request
  xmlHttp.send( null );

  return JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="playerName"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
document.getElementById('playerName').innerText = getPlayer('player1').name;
</script>
```